# Confusion on using django socialauth

Tags: django, openid, django-socialauth

http://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth/tree/master/socialauth/

I'm a bit confused on how I should use this. Of course, I read the notes at the bottom but I'm a Django novice so I'll need a little hand holding.

The structure of this looks like a project structure since it contains a `urls.py` but I'm also aware that applications can also have that. It also has a `manage.py` which leads me to believe it's a project ( plus the subdirectories ).

So should I just be integrating portions of this into my existing project? This isn't an application, right?

The README also mentions grabbing API Keys. So if I want a standard interface where you click on a google/yahoo logo and it forwards itself via Javascript to the authentication page where you login if you already aren't logged in, kicks you back to your own page, would I need API keys?

Any other special tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[We wrote this]

1. There are quite a few forks, which are ahead of us so you might want to use that.
2. If you just want openid, you dont need API Keys
3. If you want twitter/FB you definately need keys.
4. urls.py and manage.py are too show a demo app.
5. socialauth is the django app, which you can pull out.

Comment: I see now. Can you recommend a specific fork to use?

Comment: Ok. I moved over `socialauth` and `openid_consumer` to my project root. I added both to `settings.py`. I also set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/login/done/'` and `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'`. I `syncdb`'d and went to `/accounts/` and clicked on the Google link, it successfully returned me back to the homepage. I didn't get the edit profile link. Could that be because I didn't setup a url pattern for `socialauth.views.signin_complete` ?

Comment: Another note - from the localsettings I only took `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',                      'socialauth.auth_backends.OpenIdBackend',)` and put it into my settings.py, nothing else. BTW - for now I only care about gmail/openID/yahoo, not facebook or twitter.

Comment: If you still havent got this working, email me on shabda@<stackoverflowusername>.com and I will help you set this up.

Comment: i'm exactly in the same situation as meder and would like to know how you managed to redirect to edit page and after to the page where the '@login_required' was asked? thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would use the fork from agiliq (same guys).

If you look at the commits in agiliq and uswaretech, you will see that the agiliq fork has more recent commits.

- https://github.com/agiliq/Django-Socialauth/commits/master
- https://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth/commits/master

And you could also use django-social-auth, which might seem to be another fork, but it's a completely different implementation.