# What's the best and most recent social authentication plugin for Django?

Tags: django, openid, socialauth

There are plenty of them out there but a lot of them are old - can anyone recommend a plugin which they recently implemented?

The only thing I really care about is gmail/yahoo, facebook and twitter are optional.

**EDIT: To address the answer,**

[Confusion on using django socialauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421993/confusion-on-using-django-socialauth)

^ the author says there are newer forks, those are what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's kind of what's cool about github - it tracks forks for you and draws a cool little network graph. From that, you can easily find [the most recently updated fork](http://github.com/stryderjzw/Django-Socialauth)

Just click on the 'Network' button to see the graph.

Comment: Sweet, didn't know that, I only learned yesterday that you could send links to specific lines of code. Github just gets better and better..

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [Django Socialauth](http://github.com/uswaretech/Django-Socialauth)?

> This is a application to enable
> authentication via various third party
> sites. In particular it allows logging
> in via
>
> 1. Twitter
> 2. Gmail
> 3. Facebook
> 4. Yahoo(Essentially openid)
> 5. OpenId

Comment: Yes but I came across a SO thread where the author of this plugin says it's outdated himself.

Answer (score 4):

[django-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth#readme) by Matías Aguirre is an implementation which looks pretty active as a project, as of today.

According to the README it supports all major providers (and some contributed others), basic user data population and multiple social accounts association to single users.

**Edit:** `django-social-auth` is now called [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth#readme).

[django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth#readme) by Raymond Penners is a viable alternative specifically for Django. It supports almost as many [providers](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#supported-providers), and is also very active as a project.

Comment: I'm using django-social-auth in a project, and it's worked fairly well for me so far.

Comment: @BradMontgomery: Any information regarding linked in?  Seems you need to implement your own linkedin backend.

Comment: @Chris It looks like there's a [contrib backend](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth/blob/master/social_auth/backends/contrib/linkedin.py) that will do LinkedIn authentication (and others, too!). I'm only using Google, Facebook, and Twitter, but I'd like to check out these contribs and see how well they work. Looks like it's worth checking into.

Comment: @BradMontgomery: Yes, you are correct.  I was able to integrate with linkedin and no additional backend implementation was needed.  Suppose I should have tested this before asking but do appreciate the quick response!

Comment: This is the best out of the lot. So good we switched overt to using it on opencomparison.org: http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/this-site/