# what's the best django profile / user settings application around?

Tags: django, settings, preferences, django-apps

I'm looking for a good django app that brings to me basic features like

- user profile editing
- password changing
- save settings / preferences specific to my app
- save authentication keys to external apps (twitter, rtm, facebook, ...)

I know how to extend the normal user model (see docs http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter12/#cn222)

and there are also these apps around:

- django-profile/
- idios (on github)
- django-account/

however, none of them seems to be ideal for what I want. 
Therefore, my question is, does anyone know a app that is better / more mature / more feature rich that I just didn't find?
Or do I have to roll my own app?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use django-userena.

https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena

demo: http://www.django-userena.org

Comment: does django-userena support custom settings for applications?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to inform you that you will (for now) have to put together a custom solution using django-registration/django-profiles along with django-socialregistration.

Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601487/django-registration-django-profile-using-your-own-custom-form) with and progress to [Socialnetwork Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421993/confusion-on-using-django-socialauth). On the up side, django is young so solid solutions are in the near future and you will be part of them. ;-)